# I see error with surefire error even though all my test pass, no anwers related to surefire plugin helped me

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin, liquibase-hibernate

Recently i migrated surefire plugin from 2.15  to 3.0.0-M5 and i see this below error even though all the test case passed. i dont see anything in report generated, just a empty file. Google nor stackoverflow helped me. Trying this out for almost a week, was not successful. Any idea on this? Any help will appreciated. Thanks

stacktrace details :

```
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at thre base eU tReIs httt fpai://lurels.oc

alPlease host:<AVAILABLE-PORT>/
refer to C:\myproject\target\surefire-15:33:40.193 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.reso
lver.DefaultTraversableResolver - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per
default be traversable.
reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\atest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire550827656934128985\s
urefirebooter3900377300994647315.jar C:\Users\atest\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire550827656934128985 2020-09-17T15-27-08_835-jvmRun1 surefire826710
7066485510027tmp surefire_05426397409004431606tmp"
Process Exit Code: 0
Crashed tests:
com.ServiceSpec
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit ca
lled?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\<id>\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire550827656934128985\s
urefirebooter3900377300994647315.jar C:\Users\<id>\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire550827656934128985 2020-09-17T15-27-08_835-jvmRun1 surefire826710
7066485510027tmp surefire_05426397409004431606tmp"
Process Exit Code: 0
Crashed tests:
com.ServiceSpec
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:748)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execut15:33:40.193 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationI
mpl - Setting custom ParameterNameProvider of type io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.JerseyParameterNameProvider
e(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
```

My pom.xml

```
   <properties>
        
        <!-- java compiler version -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-stringtemplate4</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdbi/jdbi3-sqlobject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-sqlobject</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${TestSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${TestResourceDirectory}</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
               
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>someclass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/hk2-locator/default</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/kie.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
                            <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Groovy test compilation -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- 2.8.0-01 and later require maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 or higher -->
                <version>3.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.0-03</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0-03</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>unit</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <TestSourceDirectory>src/test/java</TestSourceDirectory>
                <TestResourceDirectory>src/test/resources</TestResourceDirectory>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                            </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <!-- For UTC parallel execution: with below parallel type and thread count, the performance is noticable -->
                            <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>false</useUnlimitedThreads>
                            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>functional</id>
            <properties>
                <TestSourceDirectory>src/test/functional/java</TestSourceDirectory>
                <TestResourceDirectory>src/test/resources</TestResourceDirectory>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                                <!-- needed for Groovy Spock tests -->
                                <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>
                                -Xmx1024m
                            </argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>https://myurl</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central-pre-release</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <name>prereleases</name>
            <url>https://myurl</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Internal Repository</name>
            <url>https://myurl</url>

        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://myurl</url>
        </snapshotRepository>

    </distributionManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>snapshot maven dependencies</id>
            <url>https://myurl</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was:: surefire was failing to read the errors because its too big and crashing

Creating `logback.xml` in `/src/test/resources/` fixed this.

Content of logback.xml is:

```xml
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to see your own logs.
See that your test crashed the JVM execution:

> Crashed tests: com.ServiceSpec

Then see the dump files in **target/surefire-reports** with the crash errors, and see this sentence:

> Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump,
> [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

If you use JUnit5 and your **@BeforeAll** method has failed, the latest version of Surefire would fail the test, but not to crash it.

Comment: I am trying to help, but I cannot because I do not see the dump file. The previous comment only says that the user should see the dump files located in *target/surefire-reports* because these dump files contain the errors and exception cause due to these issues. They do not go to the console because they may not affect most users and may be toot trivial, and also they may be the crash.

Comment: If the JVM exits abruptly (your test calls System.exit(1)) then we have no chance to show it on the console but you may see errors in the dump files (may). Therefore we wrote the recommendations for the user in documenttaion that the Syste.exit() and Runtime.halt() MUST NOT be used in the Java libraries (Spring/Kafka had these problems).